# Creating a new Java project in Eclipse does not create a (default) package?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, package

I'm new to Java, and have been using mostly YouTube and various websites' tutorials to learn Java. I'm using Eclipse neon 3 as my IDE.

Every time a new project is created in one of these tutorials, I noticed a lot of the time that a package in the src file is created automatically , and is often times called "(default)". However, this is not the case for me; in fact, no package is created at all (pls see attached screenshot), but strangely enough, the classes I created for basic learning still ran (as far as I'm aware).

Therefore should I be concerned, and if so, how do I get the IDE to auto-create these packages? Should I just manually create a package every time I start a new project? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your screenshot, I guess you're probably using the **Navigator** view. Use **Window-->Show View-->Project Explorer** option. Also, I think the **default package** will appear only when you create a **Class** with no explicit package.

Comment: Indeed, this does seem to be the case. I switched it over to Project Explorer and I can now see my default packages. Great spot.